# mod_rewrite forwarding always forwarding to index page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have some basic URL forwarding set up in my .htaccess file to create seo friendly links. My problem is that after I added the first two rules any url that begins xxxxxx.com/cm/en forwards to the index page. xxxxxx.com/cm/en/about-condominium-calle-margarita-santa-ana gets forwarded to cm/en_index. I'm sure there is something basic I'm missing here, any help appreciated.

```
RewriteRule ^cm/en cm/en_index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cm/es cm/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^cm/en/about-condominium-calle-margarita-santa-ana cm/en_about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cm/es/nuestro-apartamentos-calle-margarita-santa-ana cm/es_about.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was to add a $ to the end of ^cm/en.

So I used:

```
RewriteRule ^cm/en$ cm/en_index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cm/es$ cm/index.php [L]
```

I'm guessing the $ means that for that rule to match there can be no more text after the cm/en or cm/es. I'm sure someone else can give a proper explanation!